# Make a terminal window 'un-hideable'

Tags: gnome, window-management, xfce4-terminal, metacity

I've been trying to get a fully embedded terminal sitting on my desktop. After searching around for some tips I finally almost have it:

```
xfce4-terminal --hide-menubar --hide-borders --hide-toolbars --title=dt --working-directory /root &
sleep 1
wmctrl -r dt -e 0,200,200,500,500 &
wmctrl -r dt -b add,sticky,below &
wmctrl -r dt -b add,skip_pager,skip_taskbar &
```

It keeps a terminal without borders etc. constantly below everything else. It also doesn't appear in taskbar etc.

My only problem is that I have a habit a using my "Hide all windows" shortcut quite a lot, and that still hides the embedded terminal, which kinda beats the purpose.

Any suggestions to make an "un-hideable" terminal window? Hackish stuff welcome.

EDIT:

My first thought was to replace Gnome's "hide all windows" with my own bash script that would hide all windows and then immediately re-show the terminal using `wmctrl`.
From the docs:

```
wmctrl -r dt -b toggle,hidden
```

should work, however it doesn't. Looking on the net it appears that it's a confirmed bug, it doesn't work now and `wmctrl` hasn't been updated in two years meaning it's unlikely to ever get fixed.

*(NB: I use Debian, Gnome, Metacity and Compton composite manager)*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in `wmctrl`, which *asks* the window manager to do the given action, but in the window manager.

Quoting from [Extended Window Manager Hints](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-1.3.html)

> Implementation note: if an Application asks to toggle **`_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN`** the Window Manager should *probably* just ignore the request, since **`_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN`** is a function of some other aspect of the window such as minimization, rather than an independent state.

Note the "probably": there is no specified behavior, and some window managers may hide the window, while others may not.

Further reading:

- [_NEW_WM_STATE](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/xdg/2009-October/011100.html) (xdg mailing list)
- [_NET_WM_STATE_HIDDEN change breaks iconification](https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-devel-list/2012-September/msg00042.html)